# Django-social-auth : Incorrect Authentication Service when using twitter

Tags: python, django, django-socialauth

when I try **http://127.0.0.1/login/twitter**, I see that it goes to Twitter to authenticate but I see the following error
                     **Incorrect authentication service**

I checked many times and the **TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY** and **TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET** are correct!

My Setting looks like the following
**dev.py**

```
INSTALLED_APPS += (
    'social_auth',
)

AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    'social_auth.backends.twitter.TwitterBackend',
    'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
)

TWITTER_CONSUMER_KEY         = 'correct key'
TWITTER_CONSUMER_SECRET      = 'correct secret'

SOCIAL_AUTH_CREATE_USERS          = True
SOCIAL_AUTH_FORCE_RANDOM_USERNAME = False
SOCIAL_AUTH_DEFAULT_USERNAME = 'John'
SOCIAL_AUTH_COMPLETE_URL_NAME  = 'socialauth_complete'
SOCIAL_AUTH_ASSOCIATE_URL_NAME = 'socialauth_associate_complete'

#LOGIN_URL          = '/login-form/'
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/'
LOGIN_ERROR_URL    = '/login/error/'

TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = (
    'social_auth.context_processors.social_auth_by_name_backends',
    'social_auth.context_processors.social_auth_by_type_backends',
)

SOCIAL_AUTH_PIPELINE = (
    'social_auth.backends.pipeline.social.social_auth_user',
    'social_auth.backends.pipeline.associate.associate_by_email',
    'social_auth.backends.pipeline.misc.save_status_to_session',
    'app.pipeline.redirect_to_form',
    'app.pipeline.username',
    'social_auth.backends.pipeline.user.create_user',
    'social_auth.backends.pipeline.social.associate_user',
    'social_auth.backends.pipeline.social.load_extra_data',
    'social_auth.backends.pipeline.user.update_user_details',
)
```

**common.py**

```
""" common settings and globals """

ADMINS = (
     ('Name', 'email@gmail.com'),
)

MANAGERS = ADMINS

# Local time zone for this installation. Choices can be found here:
# http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_zones_by_name
# although not all choices may be available on all operating systems.
# On Unix systems, a value of None will cause Django to use the same
# timezone as the operating system.
# If running in a Windows environment this must be set to the same as your
# system time zone.
TIME_ZONE = 'America/Chicago'

# Language code for this installation. All choices can be found here:
# http://www.i18nguy.com/unicode/language-identifiers.html
LANGUAGE_CODE = 'en-us'

SITE_ID = 1

# If you set this to False, Django will make some optimizations so as not
# to load the internationalization machinery.
USE_I18N = True

# If you set this to False, Django will not format dates, numbers and
# calendars according to the current locale.
USE_L10N = True

# If you set this to False, Django will not use timezone-aware datetimes.
USE_TZ = True

# Absolute filesystem path to the directory that will hold user-uploaded files.
# Example: "/home/media/media.lawrence.com/media/"
MEDIA_ROOT = ''

# URL that handles the media served from MEDIA_ROOT. Make sure to use a
# trailing slash.
# Examples: "http://media.lawrence.com/media/", "http://example.com/media/"
MEDIA_URL = ''

# Absolute path to the directory static files should be collected to.
# Don't put anything in this directory yourself; store your static files
# in apps' "static/" subdirectories and in STATICFILES_DIRS.
# Example: "/home/media/media.lawrence.com/static/"
STATIC_ROOT = ''

# URL prefix for static files.
# Example: "http://media.lawrence.com/static/"
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

# Additional locations of static files
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    # Put strings here, like "/home/html/static" or "C:/www/django/static".
    # Always use forward slashes, even on Windows.
    # Don't forget to use absolute paths, not relative paths.
)

# List of finder classes that know how to find static files in
# various locations.
STATICFILES_FINDERS = (
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
#    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.DefaultStorageFinder',
)

# Make this unique, and don't share it with anybody.
SECRET_KEY = '=0s02gxrgqpw6zbet@8_usdg4@-=#@4rqxk07k2vn)a24bv&amp;p#'

# List of callables that know how to import templates from various sources.
TEMPLATE_LOADERS = (
    'django.template.loaders.filesystem.Loader',
    'django.template.loaders.app_directories.Loader',
#     'django.template.loaders.eggs.Loader',
)

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    # Uncomment the next line for simple clickjacking protection:
    # 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
)

ROOT_URLCONF = 'vlists.urls'

# Python dotted path to the WSGI application used by Django's runserver.
WSGI_APPLICATION = 'vlists.wsgi.application'

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.sites',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'vlists',
    'vlists.apps.playlists',
    'vlists.apps.videos',
    'vlists.apps.accounts',
    # Uncomment the next line to enable the admin:
    # 'django.contrib.admin',
    # Uncomment the next line to enable admin documentation:
    # 'django.contrib.admindocs',
)

# A sample logging configuration. The only tangible logging
# performed by this configuration is to send an email to
# the site admins on every HTTP 500 error when DEBUG=False.
# See http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/logging for
# more details on how to customize your logging configuration.
LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'filters': {
        'require_debug_false': {
            '()': 'django.utils.log.RequireDebugFalse'
        }
    },
    'handlers': {
        'mail_admins': {
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'filters': ['require_debug_false'],
            'class': 'django.utils.log.AdminEmailHandler'
        }
    },
    'loggers': {
        'django.request': {
            'handlers': ['mail_admins'],
            'level': 'ERROR',
            'propagate': True,
        },
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your settings file appears to be missing a setting. You need in there:

```
SOCIAL_AUTH_ENABLED_BACKENDS = ('twitter',)
```

Note the comma at the end - you need it because it is a tuple.

Comment: SOCIAL_AUTH_ENABLED_BACKENDS was deprecated a lot of time ago already.